# Find current console size in batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I am working on a batch file and i need to print hyphens **( - )** across the screen as a separator. Is there a **fast** (under two seconds) command that can do this?

I have done multiple search queries and could not find the answer on various websites.

```
(code to find screen size) 
for /l %%a in (1,1,%screen size var%) do (set "line=%line%-")
echo %line%
```

The output should show a line of hyphens across the console.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25595256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but based upon the output from `Mode CON` as used in [gjpio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7968807/gjpio)'s answer:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=4Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('Mode CON')Do (For /L %%C In (1,1,%%B)Do @Set/P "=-"<Nul)&Echo( &GoTo :Draw
:Draw
Pause
```

If you intend to use the separator multiple times within your script you could save it to a variable:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=4Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('Mode CON')Do (For /L %%C In (1,1,%%B)Do (Call Set "separator=%%separator%%-"))&GoTo :Next
:Next
Echo Welcome to %~nx0
Echo %separator%
Pause
```

As a final afterthought, and just in case you feel that it would perform quicker, I thought I'd better provide a version using delayed expansion too:

```
@Echo Off&SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion&Set "separator="
For /F "Skip=4Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%A In ('Mode CON')Do (For /L %%C In (1,1,%%B)Do Set "separator=!separator!-")&GoTo :Next
:Next
Rem Uncomment the next line if you don't want to use delayed expansion in the rest of the script
::EndLocal&Set "separator=%separator%"
Rem Your code goes here
Echo Welcome to %~nx0
Echo %separator%
Pause
```

As an addition to all of the above, you could also leverage [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) to do this too:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F %%A In ('Powershell -NoP "Write-Host('-' * $(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width)"')Do Set "separator=%%A"
Echo Welcome to %~nx0
Echo %separator%
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can work out the batch commands retrieve the `columns` value you could use the output from the MODE command;

```
    MODE CON
```

```
C:\Users\gjp>mode con

Status for device CON:  
----------------------  
    Lines:          9001  
    Columns:        120  
    Keyboard rate:  31  
    Keyboard delay: 1  
    Code page:      850
```

Comment: Thank you, but i was looking to be able to save the output to a variable and create a line on the screen

Comment: @FrederickReynolds, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6359820)...

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "skip=4 tokens=2" %%A IN ('mode CON') do (
    for /L %%B IN (1 1 %%A) do set "hyphen=!hyphen!-"
    echo !hyphen!
    goto :subroutine
)

:subroutine
echo You may continue here
pause
```

which is a bit complicated, but should do what you want.

The code searches for the columns in `mode CON`'s command output and adds to `hyphen` variable these accordingly.

Comment: How is your answer 'really' any different from my delayed expansion version?

Comment: Mine was written and accepted before yours was even posted. In cases such as this a responsible member would have suggested making minor improvements to the existing answer, if it was agreed to be an improvement. I could argue that mine is better and you may champion that yours is easier on your eye, but, other than you used a different delimiter, they're essentially they're the same answer, and there was no point in you posting it.

Comment: Just for the sake of continuing your pointless argument, I used the `:` delimiter because, regardless of which line from the `Mode CON` output was needed, only the `Skip` number would have needed to be adjusted, in yours, a modifier would need to adjust both the `Skip` and the number of `Tokens`. My example shows how to adjust the code, in order to disable delayed expansion again, without affecting the users code below it, yours doesn't. Mine ensures that any pre-defined variable does not affect the line of hyphens, yours doesn't, and for the sake of completeness, I included 2 other examples!